# Angular - Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'find') in ng-select

Tags: angular

I am having this code in my Angular-15 application:

**component.ts:**

```
import { CountryService } from 'src/app/features/admin/services/country.service';

export class CountryCreateComponent {

  countriesDatas!: any[];
  selectedCountryCode!: string;
  selectedCountryName!: string;
  showDiv: boolean = false;

  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private toastr: ToastrService
  ) {
  }

  createCountry() {
    this.createCountryForm = this.fb.group({
      CountryCode: ['', [Validators.required]],
      CountryName: ['', [Validators.required]],
    });
  }

  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private countryService: CountryService,
    private toastr: ToastrService,
    private bsModalRef: BsModalRef,
    private modalService: BsModalService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {;
    this.createCountry();
    this.loadAllCountries();
  }

  this.loadAllCountries(){
    this.countryService.getCountriesDropdown().subscribe({
      next: (res: any) => {
        this.countriesDatas = res.data;
        this.isLoading = false;
      }
    })
  }

  onCountryChange() {
    const selectedCountry = this.countriesDatas.find(
      (country) => country.countryCode === this.selectedCountryCode
    );
    this.selectedCountryName = selectedCountry
      ? selectedCountry.countryName
      : '';
  }
}
```

I want to populate the text input fields with selected CountryCode and CountryName using ng-select dropdown.

**component.html**

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="Country"
    >Country:</label
  >
  <ng-select
    [items]="countriesDatas"
    [selectOnTab]="true"
    [searchable]="true"
    bindValue="CountryCode"
    bindLabel="CountryName"
    placeholder="Select Country"
    [multiple]="false"
    [clearable]="true"
    [(ngModel)]="selectedCountryCode"
    (ngModelChange)="onCountryChange()"
    required
    formControlName="CountryCode"
  >
  </ng-select>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="divshow">
 <div class="form-group">
  <input
    type="text"
    class="form-control"
    formControlName="CountryName"
    id="CountryName"
    [value]="selectedCountryName"
  />
 </div>
</div>
```

When the ng-select is onChanged, I want to load the selected CountryName into the text input in

But I got this error:

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'find')
```

and it points at: const selectedCountry = this.countriesDatas.find(

How do I resolve this?

Comment: It seems you are selecting the dropdown before the `countriesDatas` variable is assigned with value. But it is quite odd cause if `countriesDatas` is undefined, suppose there will not have any option in the select element.

Comment: @YongShun - What do I do? ny other way around it? Kindly assist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can just initialize your app a bit different

```
  countriesDatas: any[] =[];
  selectedCountryCode: string = '';
  selectedCountryName: string = '';
```

instead of telling the typescript that you undefined values cannot be null or undefined with `!`, just set a default value. Next thing i would check if `res.data` is not undefined as well in you subscription. Since you use any types you will get no help from typescript to help you catch bugs, so i suggest setting up the an interface matching the response.